# XNA Creating a instance of a game in viewport

Tags: xna, viewport

I have two class:

1) onePlayerGame.cs
This class defines the 4 viewports on the screen

2) game1.cs
This class is a simple game

How do i go about about making game1 run on one of the viewports? Both of the class run well...but i am not sure of how to make the game "appear" on one of the viewports..

Oh...i'm doing a 2D project

HELP PLS~~~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To render games in split screen, you can simply instantiate a [ViewPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.viewport_members.aspx) object and [assign it to the graphics device](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevice.viewport.aspx) when you go to render the items in that particular viewport.

Each distinct view will need it's own rendering routine ... here's a good example:
http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/viewports-split-screen